# Как узнать пароль на root?

Tags: настройки, root, debian

Здравствуйте. В нетбуке стоит Линукс (`Debian GNU/Linux 4.0\n\l`). Настроен на заводе-изготовителе. Не можем обновить браузер и флешплеер, так как мы user. Подскажите, как можно узнать пароль на root, чтобы можно было сделать все обновления.

Comment: Обратиться к документации?)

Comment: У меня в [блоге][1] описано три способа восстановления. [1]: http://r1za4.blogspot.com/2012/01/root.html

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как узнать пароль на root](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/348348/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-root)

Answer (score 1):

Можно сбросить В Debian работает  http://itshaman.ru/articles/12/passwd-root-linux

Comment: Спасибо огромное.

Answer (score 1):

Делаем так. Загружаемся со вспомогательного диска. Дальше выполняем команды

```
mkdir recoverymount /dev/hdaX recoverycd recovery/etcvi shadowvi passwd
```

где `/dev/hdaX` - это тот раздел, где находится корень системы (например, `/dev/hda1`). В редакторе ищем строку, содержащую что-то вроде

> `root:weeWRSF!sfDFs:12581:0:99999:7:::`

и удаляем все между вторым и третьим двоеточием

> `root::12581:0:99999:7:::`

сохраняемся и выходим из редактора. Выполняем команду

```
unmount /dev/hdaX recovery
```

и перезагружаем систему

```
reboot
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное.

Answer (score 1):

Я у себя сбрасывал рутовский пароль так: зашол в загрузчик(GRUB) и написал "init=/bin/bash" потом "passwd" далее ввел новый пароль "xxx"  потом повторил пароль "xxx"

Comment: Спасибо огромное.

Answer (score 0):

... А по умолчанию разве на root пароль в linux есть? Заведите пароль на root сами:

```
$ sudo passwd
```

Comment: Когда мы в 2009 году купили нетбук, то при первом включении на мониторе высветилось: имя - user. И далее предлагалось ввести пароль. Всё. Видимо, все настройки по умолчанию.