# Как узнать пароль на root

Tags: linux, ubuntu

как можно изменить пароль? не могу войти на компьютер. спрашивает пароль пользователя? как я могу найти его.

Comment: Пароль совсем неизвестен или просто не подходит?

Answer (score 4):

По поводу заголовка вопроса:В Убунте вход от имени пользователя root по-умолчанию запрещён, и пароля у него нет. Воспользуйтесь командой sudo и вводите *свой* пароль. Пользователь, соответственно, должен иметь привилегии (см /etc/sudoers).[Ссылко](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%B2_ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

Узнать пароль просто так не получится, но зато его можно сбросить, установить
новый. Есть несколько простых способов это сделать.

#### Загрузка в однопользовательский режим

Если на нужной машине в качестве загрузчика используется GRUB без пароля,
подойдут такие действия.

1. Включите компьютер и дождитесь экрана выбора ОС (если выбор не появляется,
   нужно нажать клавишу <kbd>ESC</kbd> во момент загрузки).
2. Как только удалось попасть в меню загрузчика, наведите курсор на нужную
   систему и нажмите клавишу <kbd>E</kbd>. Вы попадёте в простой редактор для
   этого пункта.
3. Найдите строчку, начинающуюся с `linux`, и добавьте в конец слово
   `single`.
4. Загрузитесь с изменёнными настройками, нажав <kbd>F10</kbd>.
5. Через некоторое время вы попадёте в привилегированный режим. Наберите там
   команду `passwd пользователь` и установите пароль указанного пользователя
   системы.
6. Затем введите команду `exit`, и загрузка продолжится как обычно. Но пароль
   уже будет сменён.

#### Подмена демона инициализации

Однопользовательский режим загрузки может быть заблокирован*. В этом случае
можно попытаться подменить путь к программе начальной инициализации.

1. Для этого на этапе редактирования настроек пункта в загрузчике (см. №3
   выше) надо вместо параметра `single` писать `init=/bin/bash`.
2. Загрузившись (клавиша <kbd>F10</kbd>), надо примонтировать корневой раздел
   на запись.

   ```
   mount -w -o remount /
   ```
3. Затем аналогично меняете пароль утилитой **passwd**.
4. А потом перезагружаете компьютер командой `reboot -f`. Пароль будет
   изменён.

<sup>* в systemd это делается маскированием юнита `rescue.target`.</sup>

#### Загрузка с Live образа

Администратор может запретить менять параметры загрузки, [поставив пароль на
GRUB](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)#.D0.97.D0.B0.D1.89.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B0_.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.B3.D1.80.D1.83.D0.B7.D1.87.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B0_.D0.BF.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BC). Это осложнит предыдущие пункты, и придётся прибегнуть к помощи
установочной флешки.

1. Загрузив Live систему с флешки (или по-старинке с CD), в терминале
   примонтируйте системный раздел целевой ОС. Найти его можно утилитами
   **fdisk** или **GParted**.

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sdaN /mnt
   ```
2. Потом смените корневой каталог

   ```
   sudo chroot /mnt /bin/bash
   ```
3. Смените пароль также как и в предыдущих вариантах программой **passwd**.
4. И перезагрузите компьютер с изменённым паролем.

В качестве противодействия этому варианту предлагается поставить пароль и на
BIOS и повесить замок на корпус или опечатать его.

#### Редактирование базы данных пользователей

В предыдущем случае, чтобы прошёл фокус со сменой корня, подопытная система и
система с флешки должны быть архитекурно совместимы. Если это не так, можно
отредактировать файл `/etc/passwd` целевой ОС.

1. Откройте **passwd** файл, который содержит список пользователей, в любом
   текстовом редакторе (или даже в любой ОС, в которой есть поддержка линуксовой
   ФС).
2. Найдите нужного пользователя (имена в первой колонке до двоеточия) и
   уберите любые символы вплоть до второго двоеточия в строке. Это сбросит
   пароль пользователя на пустой.

   *Пример:* в файле было

   ```
   root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
   ```

   должно получиться

   ```
   root::0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
   ```
3. Загрузившись в целевую систему желательно заново установить пароль.

Но на самом деле, что по-настоящему защитить данные от несанкционированного
доступа, их стоит зашифровать. В этом случае можно быть уверенным, что
вышеизложенные инструкции не подойдут. А если вы вдруг забыли пароль от
криптоконтейнера, то самое простое решение — забыть про него. Впрочем, это не
тема настоящего ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Никак.

Можно только сбросить на новый при наличии физического доступа к машине - http://habrahabr.ru/post/54103/

Answer (score 1):

в бубунте можно зайти от рута через режим восстановления